# How to fix Code Blocks Unresolved External?

Tags: c++, borland-c++

Recently I installed CodeBlocks and Borland C++ as the compiler to just make a C program. But when I started to build it gives an error.

```
bcc32.exe -q   -IE:\Borland\Include -o"C:\Users\thamidu\Documents\Thamidu's Documens\Self Learning\C++\helloc.obj" -c "C:\Users\thamidu\Documents\Thamidu's Documens\Self Learning\C++\helloc.c"
C:\Users\thamidu\Documents\Thamidu's Documens\Self Learning\C++\helloc.c:
ilink32.exe -q -ap   -LE:\Borland\Lib -LE:\Borland\Lib\PSDK c0x32 "C:\Users\thamidu\Documents\Thamidu's Documens\Self Learning\C++\helloc.obj","C:\Users\thamidu\Documents\Thamidu's Documens\Self Learning\C++\helloc.exe",,,,
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_VCL_Init' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_MEM_UseBorMM' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_VCLLIB_Linkage' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__ExceptInit' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'GetModuleHandleA' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__startup' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__GetExceptDLLinfoInternal' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'HeapAlloc' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_SetValue' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_InitThread' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_Alloc' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_GetValue' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'GetProcessHeap' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external 'HeapFree' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_ExitThread' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '___CRTL_TLS_Free' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '_printf' referenced from C:\USERS\THAMIDU\DOCUMENTS\THAMIDU'S DOCUMENS\SELF LEARNING\C++\HELLOC.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__matherr' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__matherrl' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__fmode' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__argv_expand_ptr' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__wargv_expand_ptr' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__handle_setargv' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__handle_exitargv' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__handle_wsetargv' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__handle_wexitargv' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__fileinfo' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__setargv__' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__setenvp__' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Error: Unresolved external '__turboFloat' referenced from E:\BORLAND\LIB\C0X32.OBJ
Process terminated with status 2 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Please how can i get rid of this?? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those missing symbols are from the Borland-C++ Compiler libraries.

Since you're using Code::Blocks add these to the `Link Libraries` pane on your project's build options (Menu Bar->Project Options->Linker Settings):

- cw32.lib - Single Threaded
- cw32i.lib - Single Threaded (Dynamic)
- cw32mt.lib - Multi Threaded
- cw32mti.lib - Multi Threaded (Dynamic)

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. But it nearly worked cause the previous error  has gone. But I got an error again. After I googling for libraries i found that i must only add cw32.lib and import32.lib only for the linker and now its work fine. However thank you for your help.